# Executing tasks in various intervals

Tags: php, pseudocode

I have table in my mysql as follows :

```
+----+---------------+--------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| id | report_name   | report_id    | rinterval            | last_run            |
+----+---------------+--------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | test report 1 | 434234234234 | every morning        | 2016-05-20 12:55:07 |
|  2 | test report 2 | 3434232      | every sunday morning | 2016-05-20 12:55:07 |
|  3 | test report 3 | 342423423    | never                | 2016-05-20 12:55:07 |
|  4 | test report 4 | 4324234      | every morning        | 2016-05-20 12:55:07 |
+----+---------------+--------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

I am trying to create a php script (preferably) that when is called, runs the appropriate report. I would like some suggestions on the best way to do that.

Let's assume I set a cron job to call the script every morning, and the intervals are as above (+similar): (every morning, every sunday, twice a month, etc). Also let's assume that the scripts should not run automatically if less than 24 hours have passed. Also a manual call can be initiated.

I was thinking something like this :

```
Call script
Find what day and time it is
Find what day it is
Select * from above where day and time more than 24 hours
Iterate the above records and run the reports (report is run like http://example.com/report_name/report_id)
If rinterval reads "every morning" - run the report
If rinterval reads "every Sunday morning" - run the report if it is Sunday (and similar for other days using a case)
If rinterval reads "never" - do not run the report
if rinterval reads "twice a month" - find the last day run and see if the interval is more than 15 - if yes run it. (or similar)
```

In all the above cases, on succesfull run, update the last_run timestamp.
One of my problems is what happens if I run a manual call - or if I want to run 2 manual calls 2 minutes apart for testing. If I run the report say on Monday afternoon, I still want it to be run on Tuesday morning. Should I introduce another column that indicates if this is manual call or automatic? I still need to know that the run was made if it is manual, but do not want to break the schedule as the report must be run before 08.00 in the morning.

What are your thoughts? I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this. I am open to all suggestions, I am doing this from scratch.

Comment: there are easier ways to do this.  Cron jobs are one example.  Task Scheduling is another (depending on the kind of server you are running)

Answer (score 0):

> One of my problems is what happens if I run a manual call - or if I want to run 2 manual calls 2 minutes apart for testing

That's depends on what your scripts are doing.

> I still need to know that the

Then simply keep log of invocations (separate table) with i.e. name of script, date of invocation, way of invocation.